# What database to use for a C# desktop application

Tags: c#

I want to create a C# desktop application, the application must be used in different computers. I want a database to connect to remotely since my application will in different computers.

Comment: You can use any database, it doesn't have any barrier for that

Comment: different databases can be used, it's the matter of which db you know better and which is more suited to your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft SQL Server.  SQL Server integrates best with the tools of C# / VS.  If you data is not large, the free [Express edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) is great for you.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL server is easy to use. If you have other options such as MySql or even a no sql database like MongoDb.

Id you are using entity framework it's easier to use Sql server.